# How to store a Collection of Objects in the Clipboard?

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, clipboard

I have a class `Slide`, of which I want to place several instances in the clipboard. It works perfectly fine for a single instance.
But when I try to, for example, put a  `List<Slide>` in the clipboard, the `SetDataObject` call will silently fail.
Internally, a COMException will be thrown and is swallowed. This is because `List` does not implement `ISerializeable`.
So, `List<T>` seems not to be an option. What would be the proper approach to place a collection of `Slide` instances in the clipboard?

Comment: Can you please share the code, i need the same, but i am not getting how to use list.

Comment: @sandeep.gosavi: This is the code I ended up using back then. Hopefully it'll help you: https://gist.github.com/oliversalzburg/6676969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my assumptions were incorrect. I simply forgot a `ToList()` call and was only passing in the `IEnumerable` to `SetData`. After adding that, it is put into the clipboard just fine.

This is the code I ended up using back then:

```
public void CopySelectedSlidesToClipboard() {
  // Construct data format for Slide collection
  DataFormats.Format dataFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat( typeof( List<Slide> ).FullName );

  // Construct data object from selected slides
  IDataObject dataObject = new DataObject();

  List<Slide> dataToCopy = SelectedSlides.ToList();
  dataObject.SetData( dataFormat.Name, false, dataToCopy );

  // Put data into clipboard
  Clipboard.SetDataObject( dataObject, false );
}

public void PasteSlidesFromClipboard() {
  // Get data object from the clipboard
  IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
  if( dataObject != null ) {
    // Check if a collection of Slides is in the clipboard
    string dataFormat = typeof( List<Slide> ).FullName;
    if( dataObject.GetDataPresent( dataFormat ) ) {
      // Retrieve slides from the clipboard
      List<Slide> slides = dataObject.GetData( dataFormat ) as List<Slide>;
      if( slides != null ) {
        Slides = Slides.Concat( slides ).ToList();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is serializable. While you lose the strong typing, you can always cast on the way out.

Comment: That might be an option. Although I would prefer a solution that retain the type information.

Comment: In that case, use a straight array of type Slide.

Comment: Yeah, that completely slipped my mind. But it turns out `List` actually does work. My mistake.